# Custom Sonar Javascript plugin rule to check for a particular method call across multiple source files

Tags: java, javascript, sonarqube

I'm trying to create a custom rule for the Sonar javascript plugin to check that an init() function has been called in one of several js source files. I start off by subscribing to call expressions:

```
public void init() {
    subscribeTo(EcmaScriptGrammar.CALL_EXPRESSION);
}
```

I then make sure the init() function has been called by overriding the visitNode method:

```
public void visitNode(AstNode node){
    String functionCall=new String();
    List<Token> tokens = node.getTokens();
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++){
       functionCall+=tokens.get(i).getValue();
    }
    if(functionCall.equals("init()"))
        callMade=true;
}
```

Finally, upon leaving the file I create a violation if init() wasn't called:

```
public void leaveFile(AstNode node){
    if(!callMade)
        getContext().createLineViolation(this,"No call to init()",node);
}
```

This works just fine, however violations are created for each js source file that doesn't contain init(). I want a violation to be created only if init() is not called in any of the js source files. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unhappily not possible for the time being.

Comment: Any suggestions for a work-around? This would be a really helpful feature to make sure our code is making certain API calls.